# Use Rx with typed message broker

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have a typed message broker similar to what Caliburn provides:

```
public interface IMessageBroker
{
    void Publish<T>(T message);
    IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> subscriber);
}
```

How can I to convert subscriptions to IObservable?

I want an extension method, something like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> Subscribe<T>(this IMessageBroker messageBroker)
{
    var subject = new Subject<T>();
    messageBroker.Subscribe<T>(subject.OnNext);
    return subject;
}
```

problem in this implementation is that I can't unsubscribe and so it leaks.

Better name for Subscribe method is also welcomed.

Comment: Some contradiction here, your text says you want to convert to IObservable, but your code says 'Subscribe', which implies you want to return a subscription? Is that what is implied by your request for a better name? In which case, the better name would be ToObservable...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `ToObservable` looks good and quite descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(this IMessageBroker messageBroker)
{
    IObservable<T> observable = Observable.CreateWithDisposable<T>(o =>
        {
            return messageBroker.Subscribe<T>(o.OnNext);
        });
    return observable;
}
```

Which you should be able to use like this:

```
var observableBroker = messageBroker.ToObservable<int>();
var subject = new Subject<int>();
observableBroker.Subscribe(subject.OnNext);

//alternatively, there are overloads of Observerable.Subscribe which take lambdas:
observableBroker.Subscribe(t => DoSomethingWith(t));
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is subject really not used anywhere?

Comment: @Konstantin, woops! You're right, corrected (but still not tested...)

Comment: Your suggestion has been tested now and it is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Konstantin, good :) Note that ToObservable (as a name) is also coherent with the rx extensions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**Tested**)

> How can I to convert subscriptions to IObservable?

You can, using the the `Observable.Create` by creating the following extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>(this IMessageBroker messageBroker)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer => messageBroker.Subscribe<T>(observer.OnNext));
}
```

Note: [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) nuget package doesn´t have `Observable.CreateWithDisposable`

Or without [Rx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) (why? may be not wanting dependencies):

```
public static IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>(this IMessageBroker messageBroker)
{
    return new DelegateObservable(observer => messageBroker.Subscribe<T>(observer.OnNext));
}

public class DelegateObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private Func<IObserver<T>, IDisposable> subscriber;

    public DelegateObservable(Func<IObserver<T>, IDisposable> subscriber)
    {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return this.subscriber(observer);
    }
}
```